# Thermal decomposition products of polyurea?

Tags: polymers, plastics

Are the thermal decomposition products of polyurea polymers known, especially of the urea group, in the absence of water?

Looking at the formula

```
R-NH-C=O
     |
    HN-R
```

there appears to be no obvious candidate for a decomposition product - not enough oxygen for CO<sub>2</sub>, not enough hydrogen for Ammonia.

Any ideas or, even better, references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [one abstract](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/pol.1982.170200703/abstract):

> The primary fragmentation processes in the thermal decomposition of polymers were studied in detail on a series of structurally related polyureas by direct pyrolysis with a mass spectrometer. Our results indicate that polyureas I–III undergo a quantitative depolycondensation process analogous to that observed for N-monosubstituted polyurethanes. The thermal decomposition of polyureas IV–VI proceeds by intramolecular hydrogen transfer processes that occur at higher temperatures with respect to depolycondensation. Polycarboxypiperazine VI is decomposed by a single-stage decomposition mechanism that leads to fragments with amino end groups and carbon oxide.

I took a look at the article.  Depolycondensation is accurate: most of the polyureas examined decomposed to the "parent" isocyanates and amines.  The temperature range examined was 150°C to 350°C.

If you're interested in what happens at higher temperatures, I would guess a decomposition to mixtures of CO, ammonia, water, and possibly methane and/or hydrogen.  But I didn't find any references that would support me after a quick look

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was indeed the sort of answer I was looking for.